# C#, Volatile Read without MemoryBarrier?

Tags: c#

In the [WeakEventHandler GIT repo](https://github.com/tom-englert/WeakEventHandler.Fody) I found a piece of code I don't understand. Can anybody explain what the idea of this code is?

```
    private static class Volatile
    {
        public static T Read<T>(ref T value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

How can this method return the actual value of `value`? `value` could be cached in some register.

Am I missing something?

Update: The code is situated in this [file](https://github.com/tom-englert/WeakEventHandler.Fody/blob/master/WeakEventHandler/WeakEventHandlerFodyWeakEventAdapter.cs#L122).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be able to tell us *which file* you've seen that in, rather than forcing people to search the whole repository could you?

Comment: Found it (luckily it was in the second file I clicked): https://github.com/tom-englert/WeakEventHandler.Fody/blob/master/WeakEventHandler/WeakEventHandlerFodyWeakEventAdapter.cs#L122

Comment: Worth noting it's inside a `#if NET40` section, along with a definition for `WeakReference<T>` - looks like the code is overriding the default behaviour of both when compiled under a certain target, rather than trying to replicate it - it'll use the normal implementations if it's compiled without that set.

Comment: For the `System.Threading.Volatile` class, the JITter will recognize the method call and supply the appropriate implementation at runtime, depending on the architecture/CPU. But this doesn't apply to arbitrary classes named this way. The author likely decided to support .NET 4.0 at some point and added a simple but incorrect `Volatile.Read` implementation. Since it's only used for getting a `List<T>` field reference inside a loop which also uses `Interlocked` (which issues a full memory barrier), it works more or less by accident.